# Why is this Next 13 API route returning a blank page?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using Next 13 and I'm trying to figure out a simple API route. I just want to return `a: "hi"` when I navigate to `localhost:3000/api/auth`. I do not see a 404 error or any errors in the terminal or console. Here's the code for my API route:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function GET(request: Request) {
    return NextResponse.json({a: "hi"})
}
```

Here's the file tree of the `app` directory (where my API route is).

```
├───api
│   └───auth
├───Components
├───Reserve
│   └───[slug]
│       └───Components
├───Restaurant
│   └───[slug]
│       ├───Components
│       └───Menu
│           └───Components
└───Search
    └───Components
```

Any ideas here? I'm using Next 13.2 in the `/app/api`directory.

Comment: Can you show your files structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `export default` instead of just `export`.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
    return NextResponse.json({a: "hi"})
}
```